# Unable to find extension '' in context 'mycontext' while transferring call with option t in dial() in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, transfer, phone-call, ivr

So i am adding a call transfer facility in my code .When user dials the number of executive and executive picks the then executive has the authority to transfer the call to specific extension

```
[from-pstn]
exten=>_X.,1,Playback(hello-world)
exten=>_X.,n,set(__GOTO_ON_BLINDXFR=from-pstn^123456^1)
exten=>_X.,n,Goto(mycontext)

[mycontext]
exten=>_X.,1,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${9xxxxxxxxx},,mtG(recordvoice,${EXTEN},1))

[recordvoice]
exten=>_X.,1,Mixmonitor(myvoice.wav)
```

description of t option in dial

```
t: Allow the called user to transfer the call by hitting the blind xfer keys (features.conf) Does not affect transfers initiated through other methods.

    If you have set the variable GOTO_ON_BLINDXFR then the transferrer will be sent to the context|exten|pri (you can use ^ to represent | to avoid escapes), example: SetVar(GOTO_ON_BLINDXFR=woohoo^s^1); works with both t and T
```

but when call connects and executive press '#'(default call transfer key) then call is not transfer and cli shows

```
Unable to find extension '' in context 'mycontext'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default asterisk search for the extension in the same context and it receives an empty extention. You can specify extension by pressing the extention after pressing # and in your dialplan you can route it to different context.For ex

```
[from-pstn]
exten=>_X.,1,Playback(hello-world)
exten=>_X.,n,set(__GOTO_ON_BLINDXFR=mycontext^123456^1)
exten=>_X.,n,Goto(mycontext,111,1)

[mycontext]
exten=>123,1,Goto(from-pstn)
exten=>111,1,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${9xxxxxxxxx},,mtG(recordvoice,111,1))

[recordvoice]
exten=>111,1,Mixmonitor(myvoice.wav)
```

and when the call is connected press 123 after # to transfer the call.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

would you try with

`[mycontext]
exten=>_X.,1,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${9xxxxxxxxx},,mtG(recordvoice,${EXTEN},1))`

instead of `n`